# how make chart (with optional date range) independent from chart table in one Datastudio report?

Tags: looker-studio

I have this Datastudio report with one Chart (with optional date range)  and one table showing all cases.
Issue is that when I change date range for chart, it also change table values accordingly.
I understand this logic, but what if I want have one separate table showing all numbers of all time next to this selectable time chart.
Is it even possible?

So can I have two data objects independent in one report ?

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/23ff0aaf-629c-495b-a629-a92d52af15e9

[image]

here is  website with all reports
https://webcovid19.live/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Groups

[Minhaz Kazi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811367/12892553) on [Groups](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9209580) would be the way to go.
For future reference, adding a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d3b0da88-0306-47db-b150-2227db68576f/page/ByPQB) and a GIF to elaborate on the method:

[image]

### Original Post

It can be achieved by setting the *Default Date Range* of the [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) to `Custom` and then setting the *Date Range* as required (in this case, the default, `Auto Date Range` will do the trick).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d3b0da88-0306-47db-b150-2227db68576f) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nimantha's answer is a valid approach. However, this approach can be used only for the date range filter. If you change the Country/Region filter values, both charts will get updated.

If you want both date and dimension filters to apply to certain charts, you can simply group them. From the official help docs: [Restrict a filter control to specific charts](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9174029?hl=en#restrict-a-filter-control-to-specific-charts): "To do this, select the filter and one or more charts. Then use the Arrange > Group menu (or right-click and and select Group). Now, the filter only applies to the charts in this group."

Comment: One issue found when I use this scenario: filter control predefined date + Group all together > on Chromium Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, I got Datastudio internal error when I change date range from my web page https://webcovid19.live/index.html#dead_inc
,on Chrome/Firefox no issues,
who should I address this ?